# Adjust number of joomla modules based on content height

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I would like to find a way to dynamically adjust the number of modules based on main-content height. Is it possible and how ? in css ? javascript ?

The purpose is to avoid having blank page if there is no content.

Thanks in advance

Vanessa

Comment: Do you need some kind of css or js for parent div so that its height adjust accroding to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished in many ways, some more elegant than others.
The most simple one I could think of is to use Javascript only:

1. All module content is sent in the HTML. (as now)
2. Get the height of the main content.
3. While the main content is higher than the modules height, remove the last module.

Something like: **(Code not tested)**

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // Get heigth of main content
    var contentHeight = document.id('content').getHeight();

// While the height of the main content is more than 200
// and less than the height of the modules
    while(contentHeight > 200 && contentHeight < document.id('modules').getHeight()) {
        // Get the last module and remove it.
        $$('#modules .moduletable').getLast().dispose();
    }
});
```

Note that this assumes you are using mootools (which is probably already provided by your Joomla installation). Also, my element selectors may not work with your template.

Again, the server will still send all modules even if some are to be removed. Another thing is that this will start when the DOM of your webpage has been fully loaded, meaning the user might see modules disappearing. Therefore it could also be nicer to hide all the modules at the start and then use a similar loop to display the modules one by one.

EDIT:
Another sample you may prefer.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // Get heigth of main content
    var contentHeight = document.id('gkContent').getHeight();

    // While the height of the modules is more than 500
    // and less than the height of the modules
    while(document.id('gkRight').getHeight() > 500 && contentHeight < document.id('gkRight').getHeight()) {
        // Get the last module and remove it.
        var banners = $$('#gkRight .adsense2, #gkRight .bannergroup');
        if(banners.length > 0) banners.getLast().dispose();
        else break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi
I have adapt to my site but doesn't work :
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var contentHeight = document.id('gkContent').getHeight();
    while(contentHeight > 200 && contentHeight < document.id('gkRight')) {
        $$('#gkRight .bannergroup').getLast().dispose();
    }
});
</script>
You can have a look at this page : http://www.auxaffaires.fr/index.php/4-sorties-loisirs/143-velorail-du-bourbonnais-offrez

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I forgot to add ".getHeight()" after "document.id("modules").. I have edited the answer.

Comment: ok great it works I need to adjust some parameters to feat to my modules but now I understand the system thanks a lot !

Comment: oups I answer to quickly ... in this page : http://www.auxaffaires.fr/index.php/7-auto-moto it doesn't works and in this one it works http://www.auxaffaires.fr/index.php/7-auto-moto/133-votre-centre-de-controle-techn I don't understand ???

Comment: First, you only select one element to be removed with "$$('#gkRight .adsense2')", you can include more banners with $$('#gkRight .adsense2, #gkRight .bannergroup'). On the 7-auto-moto page it doesn't execute because the content height is less than 500. I'll upgrade my answer in a sec with a proposal for that.

Comment: Hi,
It's perfect, I adjust little things and put it for all box so I can publish my modules on all pages and everything is adapted to page height.
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var contentHeight = document.id('gkContent').getHeight();
    while(document.id('gkRight').getHeight() > 100 && contentHeight < document.id('gkRight').getHeight()) {
        var box = $$('#gkRight .box, #gkRight .header');
        if(box.length > 0) box.getLast().dispose();
        else break;
    }
});
thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. If you like, I would be happy if marked my answer as accepted:) That's of course your choice however. If there's anything more, please contact me by email so that we avoid any longer chat here. (Email can be found at my SO-profile).

Comment: I have accepted it of course and thank you for your proposition if I need help I will email you.